# Qt Attach a dynamic button to a window

Tags: c++, qt

So basically I want to make the following: When a button is pushed, create a button at point X with size Y which has text which is extracted from a textEdit. This is the function I have made:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released()
{
    QString a = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QPushButton* ptr = new QPushButton(a);
    addWidget(ptr); // I figured I should use this function, thing is I don't know what should call it
    ptr->show();
    ptr->setGeometry(260, 140, 40, 40);
}
```

It works, however the window appears on the 260, 140 on my desktop. I want it to be 260,140 in the main window, wherever it is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give to `QPushButton` the parent, at wich it would be lie. Use the following QPushButton's constructor:

```
QPushButton ( const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0 );
```

Code will be look like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released()
{
    QString a = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QPushButton* ptr = new QPushButton( a, this /* <------------ */ );
    ptr->show();
    ptr->setGeometry(260, 140, 40, 40);
}
```